# How to use a GET curl in postman?

Tags: html, curl, postman

I have this curl example:

```
curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://dev.ga.coach/intervention/:getworse/ -d '{"user_id": "012ab3", "section_id": "6"}'
```

When I run it through `cygwin` it's working properly! When I'm trying to import it in `postman` then it shows it as POST and I get the following response.

```
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /intervention/ was not found on this server.</p>
```

When I test `https://dev.ga.coach/intervention/:getworse/` through web browser, this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: You need to fill postman with the final URL you want. For exemple : 
`https://dev.ga.coach/intervention/:getworse?user_id=012ab3&section_id=6`
And if you set options to postman, it will automatically set the request as POST, because GET values don't have options which are not in the url !

Comment: It makes no sense to make a GET request with a request body or a Content-Type header. cURL will, it appears, allow you to do that, but it is very wrong.

Comment: @kevinniel Still no luck!

Comment: @Quentin I'm developing the `rest-apis` and I'm checking them through `cygwin` and are working! But a company that we are working with, they want to test them via `postman`. That's the issue.

Comment: Then your URL is wrong. To make a `GET` request in Postman, you have to set the same URL as you can put in your web browser. If the URL does work in a web browser, than it'll work on postman. Try diferent things

Comment: @kevinniel Actually it does not working in a `web browser`. It's working through `cygwin`.

Comment: @zinon — Fix the REST API that you are developing so that it doesn't require a GET request with a request body!

Comment: [A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) — The HTTP specification warns you that what you are trying to do may fail, and while it works in cURL, when you put it in Postman it DOES fail, so don't do it.

Comment: The point is an HTTP GET request is the same no matter where it comes from. So if it don't work on a web browser, it won't work in postman. And if it only works with cygwin, then you have probably set a really bad api ^^

Comment: @kevinniel I've updated my question and I added what I see in a web browser.

Comment: @zinon — The response you get in the browser is expected since you aren't including the Content-Type header or JSON payload that the server is expecting (but which it shouldn't expect on a GET request).

Comment: well, now you just have to read... It returns you a 400 error with a json... Now you have to correct your api to return a 200 HTTP status

Comment: @kevinniel — The 400 is because the JSON is missing

Answer (score 0):

cURL allows you to include a payload on a GET request but [the HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) says:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics;
> sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing
> implementations to reject the request.

When you try to make the same request with Postman, you are experiencing it "rejecting" the request. In this case, the rejection comes in the form of it converting to a POST request instead.

It would be appropriate to include a JSON payload on a POST request, but since it looks like you *are* trying to GET information you should move the data to the URL instead.

For example:

```
https://dev.ga.coach/intervention/012ab3/6/:getworse/
```

This will require you change your server-side code (which you, presumably, can do since you said *I'm developing the rest-apis*) to read the data from the new location.